# Drawing polyline in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

This is my coding I used in Leaflet:

```
    var pointA = new L.LatLng(28.635308, 77.22496);
    var pointB = new L.LatLng(28.984461, 77.70641);
    var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

    var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList {
    color: 'red',
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 0.5
    smoothFactor: 1

    });

    map.addLayer(firstpolyline);
```

The map is not showing any result. I just need straight line from one point to another, just visualize it, not geodetic correct. Points (in Leaflet "circles") are showing perfectly on the map.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Is your code pasted directly? If so,

```
var pointA = new L.LatLng(28.635308, 77.22496);
var pointB = new L.LatLng(28.984461, 77.70641);
var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

var firstpolyline = new L.polyline(pointList {
color: 'red',
weight: 3,
opacity: 0.5
smoothFactor: 1

});
```

has missing comma's on lines 5 & 8, and line 12 use `firstpolyline.addTo(map)`. Make it

```
var pointA = new L.LatLng(28.635308, 77.22496);
var pointB = new L.LatLng(28.984461, 77.70641);
var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
    color: 'red',
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 0.5,
    smoothFactor: 1
});
firstpolyline.addTo(map);
```

Comment: I can see only one error, and I fixed it. But polyline is still not showing on my map. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just missed a small line of code at the end. The polyline was correctly coded, but it was not added to the map as Lealflet requires: firstpolyline.addTo(map);

Answer (score 6):

I used following code to draw `polyline` between various Locations:

```
var polylinePoints = [
    [37.781814, -122.404740],
    [37.781719, -122.404637],
    [37.781489, -122.404949],
    [37.780704, -122.403945],
    [37.780012, -122.404827]
  ];            
  
  var polyline = L.polyline(polylinePoints).addTo(map);
```

For more Details you can follow [this Link.](https://www.wrld3d.com/wrld.js/latest/docs/examples/adding-a-leaflet-polyline/)

Answer (score 3):

`addLayer` doesn't work for me, had to do `.addTo(map)`

Answer (score 1):

Use lower case "polyline" in `L.polyline(...)`. This will work.

Answer (score -1):

If you want exact path(curve shapes), use polyline.antPath.